# C# Interop.Word Adding an Image from project resource folder

Tags: c#, image, ms-word, com-interop

Having some image problem with Interop.Word and C#. I want to add an image in the header of the document that I am going to generate. I have this code working perfectly

```
section.Headers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Shapes.AddPicture(@"C:\Logo.jpg", ref x, ref x, ref x, ref x, ref x, ref x, ref x);
```

Problem is that I can't have `"C:\Logo.jpg"` in the code since after publishing the project, there would most probably be no Logo.jpg in the C folder of the user. The image is already in my project's resource folder. I've used `Image.FromFile("Logo.jpg")` before but `.AddPicture` requires a string and not an image.

Any ideas?

-- edit --

Saw this over the net:

```
string anyPath = @"C:\logo.jpg";
Properties.Resources.logo.Save(anyPath);
section.Headers.[...].Shapes.AddPicture(anyPath, ...
```

but then I still get a generic error in GDI+ or ExternalException was unhandled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cant you use...

```
section.Headers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Shapes.AddPicture(@"Logo.jpg", ref x, ref x, ref x, ref x, ref x, ref x, ref x);
```

Use the relative location of the image file in the bin folder instead of an absolute positioned file

EDIT

You could use this to generate an absolute file location based on a relative link.
**Relies on using WinForms**

```
string relative = @"images\Logo.jpg";
System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(Application.ExecutablePath);
string absolute = System.IO.Path.Combine(fi.Directory.FullName, relative);
```

I don't think your updated method will work too great on vista/windows7 since they have various write permissions (maybe), not to mention, no one like random files being added to their C drive.

I think its bad practice for important files like this to not be in the application folder...

Comment: Tried it already but to no avail. I also edited the properties of the image and set Build Action to Embed Resource and Copy to Output Directory to Copy Alway but still, nothing happened.

Comment: Have you checked its there? by doing something like Console.out.println(File.Exists("logo.jpg")); ?

Comment: It returns false. But the file is already in my resource.resx and my resource folder. I'm really confused now. How can this be fixed? BTW, thanks for the time Kurru. :)

Comment: you should look into the {project folder}/bin and see if you can find your image there. I should be there somewhere if the image has "Copy to Output Directory" set to "Copy if Newer"

Comment: It's there under /bin/Debug/Resources and /bin/Release/Resources

Comment: try the above code with string relative = @"Resources\Logo.jpg"; That might work... with ...Shapes.AddPicture(absolute, ref x, ref x, ref x, ref x, ref x, ref x, ref x);

Answer (score 0):

I reluctantly - but successfully - did:

```
if (!File.Exists("singleright.png"))
{
object obj = Properties.Resources.singleright;
System.Drawing.Bitmap rs = (System.Drawing.Bitmap)(obj);
rs.Save("singleright.png");
}
insertionPoint.InlineShapes.AddPicture("singleright.png", ref LinkToFile, ref SaveWithDocument);
```

This does work - and it works on the foreign computer too when I published my Word - Addin. But I still don't like it. It should not be necessary to save an imagefile from the resources on the client computer, on should be able to use the resource directly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm stuck in the same situation, and I couldn't find a way to directly use the image resource with `InlineShapes` without having to save it before.

A nice folder to save these files is `My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp`.

Answer (score 0):

I happen to see this post and adding image from resource file is straight forward. Found a way and work for me without saving it to local machine.

```
 // PictureContentContorl                        
    Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.PictureContentControl ct;
    // Removing the control if already exists
                       Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument).Controls.Remove("HeaderLogo");
    // adding control to a range rng
                            ct = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument).Controls.AddPictureContentControl(rng, "HeaderLogo");
                            ct.Image = Properties.Resources.my_logo;
                            ct = null;
```

May be it is helpful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use project resource. Try this.

```
// Copy image to clickboard.
System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetImage( Properties.Resources.your_resource_name);

//Select an location where you want to put the image
section.Headers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range.Select();

// Page onto the document. wordApp is the instance of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
wordApp.Selection.Paste();
```